# SQL: SQL Like statement with parameter values not returning desired values

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to implement search in asp.net web application where I query a table and match search term with some columns.

To implement a partial search I thought, I can use `Like` clause. So I write my sql procedure like this -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sproc_SEARCH
    @author char(200)
AS
    SELECT * FROM Table WHERE column LIKE '%' + @author + '%'
```

Above procedure should return some rows, but it doesn't

However, If i just run following sql statement it gives me desired rows

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE column LIKE '%bha%'
```

I don't understand why this is the case, can use some help.

Thanks

Comment: How are you calling the stored procedure?

Comment: See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
@author varchar(200)
```

Answer (score 4):

It probably has to do with `@author` being a `CHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`, so you have trailing spaces. Either use `VARCHAR`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sproc_SEARCH
    @author varchar(200)
AS
    SELECT * FROM Table WHERE column LIKE '%' + @author + '%'
```

or trim your parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sproc_SEARCH
    @author char(200)
AS
    SELECT * FROM Table WHERE column LIKE '%' + RTRIM(LTRIM(@author)) + '%'
```